# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Fragment Not attached to an Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment, viewmodel

Hello Im facing an issue of "fragment not attached to an activity" on activityviewmodels()

my code:

private val dataViewModel: DataViewModel by activityViewModels()

I have written this code in Fragment which is attached to ViewPager.
and Viewpager is Attached to BaseFragment.

I have tried adding null check but still facing issue.

Comment: The "fragment not attached to an activity" error occurs when the fragment is trying to access the activity's ViewModel before it is properly attached to the activity.

Comment: What would be the solution for this ?

Comment: show code of Activity where you used setContentView method

Comment: you are probably calling `dataViewModel` too early in the Fragment, likely from another property initializer.

Comment: I have used fragments not activity

Answer (score 1):

You can try using setOffScreenPageLimit(). (If this is the use-case)